# Force Webpage to be Inaccessible on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel

I have a website that is being hosted in an AWS EC2 instance. I am using AWS RHEL (the default EC2 option).

Currently, my hosted site (on the instance) is located at: `/var/www/public_html/gitRepoName/index.html`.

Lets say I have 3 webpages in the directory `gitRepoName`. So, that would be `index.html`, `aboutMe.html`, and `adminPage.html`. How can I configure the instance such that nobody can manually type in `myUrl.com/adminPage.html` and get the admin page as a result?

In other words, how do I make sure that my individual webpages can only be accessed via clicking proper `href` tags I made, and they cannot be accessed by hard-typing in a link. Please comment with any questions.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is a proper `href` tag?

Comment: I didn't understand the part manually typing vs clicking a link. Do you refer to make the same url inaccessible if someone type it in the browser but make it accessible if someone click on  a link from webpage for the same url?

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. Lets say I have a bit of text that looks like `<a href="myNewPage.html">this</a>`. How can I force the user to click the text `this` rather than them typing `www.link.com/myNewPage` to access `myNewPage.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you have to build on the web page and not on the ec2 itself.You can use php script to get the HTTP_REFERER and check the value is equal to "myUrl.com/index.html"

The code in adminPage would be something like below:

```
  <?php
    $ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   if ($ref!="myUrl.com/index.html")
   {
      ......redirect to index.html
   }
   ?>
```

I have mentioned the php example since you have not mentioned what script language you are using.If you are using HTML/Javascript then try with document.referrer property in HTML dom.

Comment: I don't have apache serving the site, but if I chose to do so, I will try this.

Comment: But if I do this, I have a question. My understanding of the code is this: 
Get the page the user came from - 
If the page was not index, redirect to index.
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes also if HTTP_REFERER is empty on the adminPage it will still redirect the user back to the index.

Comment: @Jsleshem any web server will support a variant of this... but it's important to note that this is not considered a valid security mechanism -- it keeps honest people honest, and not much more.  `HTTP_REFERER` (derived from the `Referer:` request header) is sent by the browser and is untrusted. It was designed as a reporting and housekeeping mechanism ("wow we get a lot of 404s on `/pics/funny/cat.jpg`... I wish I knew what pages were linking there...") and not for security. It is *trivial* for a malicious user to forge.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Do you know of any other way this can be done, such that there can be little to no malicious activity? Thanks!